# EMAIL HOST Django ERROR

Tags: python, django, email, smtp

Hola tengo el siguiente problema para enviar emails atreves de Django con un @ diferente.

Lo que intento en la configuración es lo siguiente (setting.py):

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"
EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.c2430666.ferozo.com"
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_HOST_USER="correo@enredate.com.ar"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "password"
```

Views.py

```
def home(request):
    emailfrom = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
    send_mail("asunto", "mensaje", emailfrom, ["lcas83539@gmail.com"])
...
```

mi proveedor del correo me marca esto

> ```
> Servidor: c2430666.ferozo.com
> ```

> ```
> Certificado de Seguridad: Sí
> ```

> ```
> SMTP Puerto: 465
> ```

pero aun así me sale el error

> [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

Intente de diversas manera y no logro encontrar la respuesta a mi problema

Notas:

- El Cpanel es de ferozo.com
- El correo y email funcionan ya que los probé desde webmail.ferozo.com

Comment: Parece que el servidor es `c2430666.ferozo.com` y no `smtp.c2430666.ferozo.com` como tú tienes puesto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenia dos errores en esa ocasión

```
EMAIL_HOST = "c2430666.ferozo.com" #este variaba ya que no estaba seguro

EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
```

El que daba error en principal es que en ves de TLS era SSL